# lua string.find can't match "/"

Tags: lua, find

Lua string.find can't find "/" in a reverse way of find, look at the following code:

c="~/abc.123"
print(string.find(c,"/",-1,true))

This always returns "nil"

Comment: can anyone help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the Lua reference manual.
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/

```
string.find(c,"/",-1,true)
```

The third parameter of `string.find` will determin where to start the search.
As you entered `-1` you will start at the last character of your string and search forward. Of course you won't find anything that way.

For strings positive indices give a position from the beginning and negative indices give a position from the string's end.

Use 1 to start from the first character. Then you'll find your slash. Alternatively you could use anything <= -8

Please note that you could also write `c:find("/",1,true)` as a shorter version.

Answer (score 1):

To find the last occurrence of `/`, use `string.find(s,".*/")`. The second return value is the position of the last `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Lua can't do leftwards searches, consider reversing the string first:

```
function Find_Leftwards(s,m,i)
    local b,f = s:reverse():find(m, i)
    return #s-f, #s-b
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[`string.find`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.find) cannot be used to do a leftwards search of a string. The `init` parameter merely sets the position from which to begin a rightwards search:

> A third, optional numeric argument `init` specifies where to start the search; its default value is 1 and can be negative.

And an [earlier note](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4) from the manual on negative indices:

> Indices are allowed to be negative and are interpreted as indexing backwards, from the end of the string. Thus, the last character is at position -1, and so on.

You'll need to roll your own function which searches for an index starting from the right:

```
local function r_find (str, chr)
    local bchar = chr:byte(1)

    for i = #str, 1, -1 do
        if str:byte(i) == bchar then
            return i
        end
    end
end

print(r_find('~/.config/foo/bar', '/')) --> 14
```

Or consider using [`string.match`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match) to find the last section:

```
print(('~/.config/foo/bar'):match('/([^/]+)$')) --> 'bar'
```

Another option would be to simply split the string into its individual sections, and get the last section.